# Add column in dataframe from another dataframe doing some arithmetic calculations python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
id   product_1   product_2   count  
1        100       200          10
2        200       600          20
3        100       500          30
4        400       100          40
5        500       700          50
6        200       500          60
7        100       400          70
```

also  i have another table in dataframe df2

```
product    price
100         5
200         10
300         15
400         20
500         25
600         30
700         35
```

i have to create a new column `price_product2` in my first df, taking values of price from df2 with  respect to product_2.
And also find the percentage difference of product_2 with respect to product_1
and make one more column `%_diff` .

i.e `say product_1 = 100 and product_2 = 200. therefore product_2 is 200% of the price of 100.`

similarly if `product_1 = 400 and product_2 = 100, it is a decline in price.
therefore product_2 is -25% of product_1.`

my final output should be. df =

```
id   product_1   product_2    count  price_product_2  %_diff
1        100       200          10     10               +200
2        200       600          20     30               +300
3        100       500          30     25               +500
4        400       100          40     5                -25
5        500       700          50     35               +140
6        200       500          60     25               +250
7        100       400          70     20               -71.42
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?

i was trying to use map functions.

```
df['price_product_2'] = df['product_2'].map(df2.set_index('product_id')['price'])
```

but i could get only one column , how do i get the `%_diff` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` `d` with divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
d = df2.set_index('product')['price'].to_dict()
df['price_product_2'] = df['product_2'].map(d)
df['price_product_1'] = df['product_1'].map(d)
df['diff']  = df['price_product_2'].div(df['price_product_1']).mul(100)
print (df)
   id  product_1  product_2  count  price_product_2  price_product_1   diff
0   1        100        200     10               10                5  200.0
1   2        200        600     20               30               10  300.0
2   3        100        500     30               25                5  500.0
3   4        400        100     40                5               20   25.0
4   5        500        700     50               35               25  140.0
5   6        200        500     60               25               10  250.0
6   7        100        400     70               20                5  400.0
```

But it seems only divide is necessary if multiple by same constant columns `product_1` and `product_2`, then difference is same:

```
df['diff1']  = df['product_2'].div(df['product_1']).mul(100)
print (df)
   id  product_1  product_2  count  diff1
0   1        100        200     10  200.0
1   2        200        600     20  300.0
2   3        100        500     30  500.0
3   4        400        100     40   25.0
4   5        500        700     50  140.0
5   6        200        500     60  250.0
6   7        100        400     70  400.0
```

Comment: `Out of range value for column 'diff'`  i am getting this error, any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Now I am only on phone, but can you explain more? Do you use second solution?

Comment: in the final df, if i need only `diff1` and not `price_product_2  price_product_1` is there any other way other than selecting only required columns at the last.  Will `.drop(colname)` work?

Comment: something like this. `df['diff']  = df['price_product_2'].div(df['price_product_1']).mul(100).drop('price_product_2', 'price_product_1')`

Comment: You can use `d = df2.set_index('product')['price'].to_dict()`
`df['diff']  = df['product_2'].map(d).div(df['product_1'].map(d)).mul(100)`

Comment: Yes, this temporary columns cannot be created if divided maped `product_1` and `product_2`.

Comment: if my table is very very huge( approx 4 million) would `map and div` at once  take more time? or just create column and divide and then remove column ? which way would be faster?

Comment: obviously if more operations it is slowier, so I think the fastest is `df['diff'] = df['product_2'].map(d).div(df['product_1'].map(d)).mul(100)`. But `map` is necessary? If use only divide `df['product_2'].div(df['product_1']).mul(100)` it is fastest. I think map can be necessary if need `NaN` for some values which are not in dict, then map return `NaN`. What do you think?

Comment: yes map would be necessary, since price of product2 and product1 may not be in the same ratio everytime. in this dummy data it looks same, but not everytime

Comment: i used `d = df2.set_index('product')['price'].to_dict() df['diff'] = df['product_2'].map(d).div(df['product_1'].map(d)).mul(100)`  but the diff1 for some rows is showing me inf(infinite). any ideas why this is happening?
i checked with the price of product1 and 2 seperately and  they both are valid numbers, in my opinion infinite can only come when divided by 0.

Comment: Yes, I get this issue too, problem was to big int value or too small memory of PC.

Comment: any ideas how to resolve this? because i was dealing with a huge dataframe and around 30% of my rows have diff1 as `inf` :( as a temporary fix i replaced inf with Nan but that is of no use. `df['diff1'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)`

Comment: Hmmm, problem is too with small data sample? Or problem is only in big dataframe, in small it works perfect?

Comment: in small sample it works perfect, only in large dataframe this happens.
by checking `price_product2/price_product1` manually it was a genuine value, don't know why in my final df it is giving me 'inf'

Comment: unfortynately it is memmory issue. But I have solution for you - It is called [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html). Try divide by `dask`.

Comment: can you please just write a sample line of code on how to divide by `dask` it will be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, but not so easy for me. I try find some links.

Comment: You can use `http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.div` and for creating `dask dataframe` use http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge` (or `map`) twice, once for each product, then calculate the difference.

```
# Add prices for products 1 and 2
df3 = (df1.
       merge(df2, left_on='product_1', right_on='product').
       merge(df2, left_on='product_2', right_on='product'))

# Calculate the percent difference
df3['pct_diff'] = (df3.price_y - df3.price_x) / df3.price_x
```

Comment: How do i use .map twice in one single line code like you used .merge?

Comment: Not sure it's possible, but two lines would also work. `map` returns a `Series`, a one-dimensional array of numbers. `merge` returns a `DataFrame` and allows us to add columns onto it step by step.

Comment: while doing merge it is creating multiple columns of `product_1` and `product_2` but i want only 1 distinct column, how do i remove duplicate columns

Comment: you can use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), e.g. `df.drop('extra_col', 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following data frames:

```
In [32]: df1
Out[32]:
   index  id  product_1  product_2  count
0      0   1        100        200     10
1      1   2        200        600     20
2      2   3        100        500     30
3      3   4        400        100     40
4      4   5        500        700     50
5      5   6        200        500     60
6      6   7        100        400     70

In [33]: df2
Out[33]:
   product  price
0      100      5
1      200     10
2      300     15
3      400     20
4      500     25
5      600     30
6      700     35
```

It is probably easier simply to set `product` as the index for df2:

```
In [35]: df2.set_index('product', inplace=True)

In [36]: df2
Out[36]:
         price
product
100          5
200         10
300         15
400         20
500         25
600         30
700         35
```

Then you can do things like the following:

```
In [37]: df2.loc[df1['product_2']]
Out[37]:
         price
product
200         10
600         30
500         25
100          5
700         35
500         25
400         20
```

Use the values explicitly to set, or else the product index will screw things up:

```
In [38]: df1['price_product_2'] = df2.loc[df1['product_2']].values

In [39]: df1
Out[39]:
   index  id  product_1  product_2  count  price_product_2
0      0   1        100        200     10               10
1      1   2        200        600     20               30
2      2   3        100        500     30               25
3      3   4        400        100     40                5
4      4   5        500        700     50               35
5      5   6        200        500     60               25
6      6   7        100        400     70               20
```

For the percentage difference, you can also use vectorized operations:

```
In [40]: df1.product_2 / df1.product_1 * 100
Out[40]:
0    200.0
1    300.0
2    500.0
3     25.0
4    140.0
5    250.0
6    400.0
dtype: float64
```